# Hbridge for ultrasonic transmitter

Tags: h-bridge, ultrasound, transducer

I'm trying to build an ultrasonic transmitter circuit. The datasheet specifies 20V peak-peak for the ultrasonic to operate at its maximum power. However I'm limited to only using a 9V supply. What I thought about doing is making an H-Bridge to switch the polarity of the battery between 9 and -9, giving me  almost 18vpp. Do you think this is a good idea? Do you have anything else to recommend?

This is what the circuit would look like. [image: Function generator simulates a 40kHz square wave, scope is there just to look at the output.]

Comment: Are you using a separate transducer for receiving echoes?

Comment: Typically you would have three levels: +9V, 0V, -9V.

Answer (score 1):

Why re-invent the wheel when you could just use the same method used by the HC SR04 using an RS232 Tx to run the sender.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ultrasonic emission sources somewhat behave and work the same way as speakers or buzzers. 
Using a [-Vcc to Vcc] range (with a H-Bridge) is a common practice in class D audio amplifiers to double the peak-peak voltage across the membrane. So that's all right!